# How to extract specific rows from dataframe efficiently?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `mydata` with data in long format of 60 participants. I would like to end up with one data frame per participant to loop over them. As you can see below, participants have their unique ppnrXXXX and different number of rows.

| Sample_ID | Datapoint |
| --- | --- |
| ppnrR2Mdo2_05-01-2022_1500) (60.3 s) | 0.54 |
| ppnrR2Mdo2_05-01-2022_1500) (60.35 s) | 0.25 |
| ppnrR4Ksm_05-01-2022_1500) (20.3 s) | 0.68 |
| ppnrR4Ksm_05-01-2022_1500) (60.35 s) | 0.21 |
| ppnrR4Ksm_05-01-2022_1500) (60.40 s) | 0.78 |

I thought I can do something like this:

```
ppnrR2Mdo2_data <- mydata[grep("ppnrR2Mdo2", mydata$Sample_ID), ]
```

However, I have 60 participants so this would take 60 lines of code?

Is there maybe a way to loop over the rows and look at whether the ppnr changes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple datasets, either do a group by approach or `split` the data into `list` of data.frames and then loop over the `list` and apply the code

```
lst1 <- split(mydata, sub("_.*", "", mydata$Sample_ID))
```

Here, we use `sub` to match the substring starting from the `_` followed by any characters (`.*`) and then replace it with blanks (`""`) to remove those, and use that to `split` the data

```
> str1 <- "ppnrR2Mdo2_05-01-2022_1500) (60.3 s)"
> sub("_.*", "", str1)
[1] "ppnrR2Mdo2"
```

Comment: Amazing! I had to do it in separate steps as my actual String looks like this: "EMG_Corrugator_Experiment_Signal (R_124OOMtO1UKZQh5_11_2_22_1200) (4 s)". So I used `test2$Sample_ID <- sub(".*R_", "", test2$Sample_ID) 
test2$Sample_ID <- sub(").*", "", test2$Sample_ID)
lst1 <- split(test2, test2$Sample_ID)`

May I ask how I would go about finding the correct function for my problems in the future? I am a new to intermediate user but often struggle with new problems and don't know where to start looking.

Comment: @Leon164 In all programming languages, it takes a bit of time to understand the function names and its behaviors.  Otherwise, programming principles are more or less similar. I can only say that practicing more in the language you wish to learn will be a step towards achieving your goal.  Another option is to start using SO by attempting to solve questions posted by others.  You may be able to quickly familiarize with the functions in that ways